Creating multiple sliverlists with replacing sliver heads
Google has described the SliverList with the headers as is seen in this picture. They stack on top of another, which at many lists would lose a lot of screenspace used for the headers.
Is there a native way for these headers to, instead of stacking, push each other off the screen towards the top, once they reach it and replace them?

you did not include "this picture"

Man... I did but maybe it is removed because this is a new acc? I will try to add it but I hope it is also clear form my description

@pskink I added it as hyperlink
